# View of multiple tables. Need to remove "doubles" defined by 1 table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, distinct

Ok, so this is what i'm stuck with.

[image: View schema]
[Full size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEIjH.png)

```
SELECT     dbo.InstellingGegevens.INST_SUBTYPE, dbo.InstellingGegevens.INST_BRON, dbo.InstellingGegevens.INST_INSTELLINGSNUMMER, 
                      dbo.InstellingGegevens.INST_NAAM, dbo.InstellingGegevens.INST_KORTENAAM, dbo.InstellingGegevens.INST_VESTIGINGSNAAM, 
                      dbo.InstellingGegevens.INST_ROEPNAAM, dbo.InstellingGegevens.INST_STATUUT, dbo.InstellingGegevens.ONDERWIJSNIVEAU_REF, 
                      dbo.InstellingGegevens.ONDERWIJSSOORT_REF, dbo.InstellingGegevens.DATUM_TOT, dbo.InstellingGegevens.DATUM_VAN, 
                      dbo.InstellingGegevens.VERBOND_REF, dbo.InstellingGegevens.VSKO_LID, dbo.InstellingGegevens.NET_REF, dbo.Instellingen.Inst_ID, dbo.Instellingen.INST_TYPE, 
                      dbo.Instellingen.INST_REF, dbo.Instellingen.INST_LOC_REF, dbo.Instellingen.INST_LOCNR, dbo.Instellingen.Opt_KalStandaard, dbo.InstellingTelecom.INST_TEL, 
                      dbo.InstellingTelecom.INST_FAX, dbo.InstellingTelecom.INST_EMAIL, dbo.InstellingTelecom.INST_WEB, dbo.InstellingAdressen.SOORT, 
                      dbo.InstellingAdressen.STRAAT, dbo.InstellingAdressen.POSTCODE, dbo.InstellingAdressen.GEMEENTE, dbo.InstellingAdressen.GEM_REF, 
                      dbo.InstellingAdressen.FUSIEGEM_REF, dbo.InstellingAdressen.FUSIEGEM, dbo.InstellingAdressen.ALFA_G, dbo.InstellingAdressen.PROVINCIE, 
                      dbo.InstellingAdressen.BISDOM, dbo.InstellingAdressen.ARRONDISSEMENT, dbo.InstellingAdressen.GEWEST, dbo.InstellingLogin.Inst_Gebruikersnaam, 
                      dbo.InstellingLogin.Inst_Concode, dbo.InstellingLogin.Inst_DirCode, dbo.InstellingLogin.DOSSNR, dbo.InstellingLogin.Instelling_ID, 
                      dbo.InstellingContPersDirecteurs.AANSPREKING, dbo.InstellingContPersDirecteurs.CONTACTPERSOON, dbo.InstellingContPersDirecteurs.FUNCTIE
FROM         dbo.InstellingGegevens RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.Instellingen ON dbo.InstellingGegevens.INST_TYPE = dbo.Instellingen.INST_TYPE AND dbo.InstellingGegevens.INST_REF = dbo.Instellingen.INST_REF AND 
                      dbo.InstellingGegevens.INST_LOC_REF = dbo.Instellingen.INST_LOC_REF AND 
                      dbo.InstellingGegevens.INST_LOCNR = dbo.Instellingen.INST_LOCNR LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.InstellingTelecom ON dbo.InstellingGegevens.INST_TYPE = dbo.InstellingTelecom.INST_TYPE AND 
                      dbo.InstellingGegevens.INST_REF = dbo.InstellingTelecom.INST_REF AND 
                      dbo.InstellingGegevens.INST_LOC_REF = dbo.InstellingTelecom.INST_LOC_REF LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.InstellingAdressen ON dbo.InstellingGegevens.INST_TYPE = dbo.InstellingAdressen.INST_TYPE AND 
                      dbo.InstellingGegevens.INST_REF = dbo.InstellingAdressen.INST_REF AND 
                      dbo.InstellingGegevens.INST_LOC_REF = dbo.InstellingAdressen.INST_LOC_REF LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.InstellingLogin ON dbo.InstellingLogin.Inst_InstellingIKONType = dbo.Instellingen.INST_TYPE AND 
                      dbo.InstellingLogin.Inst_InstellingIKON_REF = dbo.Instellingen.INST_REF AND dbo.InstellingLogin.Inst_Loc_REF = dbo.Instellingen.INST_LOC_REF AND 
                      dbo.InstellingLogin.Inst_Loc_Nr = dbo.Instellingen.INST_LOCNR LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.InstellingContPersDirecteurs ON dbo.InstellingGegevens.INST_TYPE = dbo.InstellingContPersDirecteurs.INST_TYPE AND 
                      dbo.InstellingGegevens.INST_REF = dbo.InstellingContPersDirecteurs.INST_REF AND 
                      dbo.InstellingGegevens.INST_LOC_REF = dbo.InstellingContPersDirecteurs.INST_LOC_REF
WHERE     (NOT (dbo.InstellingLogin.Inst_InstellingIKON_REF IS NULL))
```

So here is the problem:

the 'should be' PK is a 1 varchar 3 int's key. for every key there is supposed to be 1 row in each of the tables which you can see in the image. the 'parent' of those keys is the table `Instellingen`. This table is generated with a `distinct select` of `InstellingenLogin`

the real problem is that there are about 10 doubles in `InstellingenLogin` (of about 5k records) and because of this, some rows return double in the view, with only the columns of `InstellingLogin` different.

what i want is that if there are 2 or more rows in `InstellingLogin` with the same key, that only 1 will show (the first one,... doenst matter which one, just 1 will do).

in short that means that for every record in `Instellingen` i want 1 record in this view.

is there any way to do that?

Comment: I'm a bit confused, can you show some of the duplicate data you are trying to eliminate?

Comment: a dupe row would have the same value as the other row, only the values from the `InstellingLogin` table are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit confused but I think the answer below should illustrate how to acheive what you need:

```
SELECT * FROM Instellingen as i
CROSS APPLY
(   
    SELECT TOP (1) * FROM InstellingLogin as il
    WHERE i.INST_LOC_REF = il.Inst_Loc_REF 
    and i.INST_LOCNR=il.Inst_Loc_Nr 
    and i.INST_REF=il.Inst_InstellingIKON_REF 
    and i.INST_TYPE=il.Inst_InstellingIKONType
    order by il.Datum_tot
) la
```

This will basically join on Instellingen and InstellingenLogin but only on the first record found

Comment: the idea sounds good but unfortunately something is wrong in the syntax for MS SQL

Comment: ok, i got this to work on a stand-alone merge. now to put it all together

Comment: this works, but when i run some queries on this view it takes about 2 minutes to return 5k rows! without the cross join it takes about 1s

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap `InstellingenLogin` in some kind of aggregate to remove the duplicates and then join to the result - you can do this with a subquery.  You could do a `GROUP BY` with `MIN()` or `MAX()` to pick a value or you could do `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY some_criteria PARTIION BY your_key)` and pick the first row.

Also, I recommend using aliases on your tables - makes it far more readable

```
WITH UniqueLogins AS (
    -- How to pick Inst_Gebruikersnaam, Inst_Concode, Inst_DirCode, DOSSNR, Instelling_ID, InstellingIKONType, Inst_Loc_REF, Inst_Loc_Nr, Inst_InstellingIKON_REF
    SELECT key columns, MIN(non key column), MIN(non key column), MIN(non key column)
    FROM dbo.InstellingLogin
    GROUP BY key columns
)
SELECT     G.INST_SUBTYPE, G.INST_BRON, G.INST_INSTELLINGSNUMMER, 
                  G.INST_NAAM, G.INST_KORTENAAM, G.INST_VESTIGINGSNAAM, 
                  G.INST_ROEPNAAM, G.INST_STATUUT, G.ONDERWIJSNIVEAU_REF, 
                  G.ONDERWIJSSOORT_REF, G.DATUM_TOT, G.DATUM_VAN, 
                  G.VERBOND_REF, G.VSKO_LID, G.NET_REF, I.Inst_ID, I.INST_TYPE, 
                  I.INST_REF, I.INST_LOC_REF, I.INST_LOCNR, I.Opt_KalStandaard, T.INST_TEL, 
                  T.INST_FAX, T.INST_EMAIL, T.INST_WEB, A.SOORT, 
                  A.STRAAT, A.POSTCODE, A.GEMEENTE, A.GEM_REF, 
                  A.FUSIEGEM_REF, A.FUSIEGEM, A.ALFA_G, A.PROVINCIE, 
                  A.BISDOM, A.ARRONDISSEMENT, A.GEWEST, UniqueLogins.Inst_Gebruikersnaam, 
                  UniqueLogins.Inst_Concode, UniqueLogins.Inst_DirCode, UniqueLogins.DOSSNR, UniqueLogins.Instelling_ID, 
                  CPD.AANSPREKING, CPD.CONTACTPERSOON, CPD.FUNCTIE
FROM         dbo.InstellingGegevens AS G RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                  dbo.Instellingen AS I ON G.INST_TYPE = I.INST_TYPE AND G.INST_REF = I.INST_REF AND 
                  G.INST_LOC_REF = I.INST_LOC_REF AND 
                  G.INST_LOCNR = I.INST_LOCNR LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  dbo.InstellingTelecom AS T ON G.INST_TYPE = T.INST_TYPE AND 
                  G.INST_REF = T.INST_REF AND 
                  G.INST_LOC_REF = T.INST_LOC_REF LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  dbo.InstellingAdressen AS A ON G.INST_TYPE = A.INST_TYPE AND 
                  G.INST_REF = A.INST_REF AND 
                  G.INST_LOC_REF = A.INST_LOC_REF LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  UniqueLogins ON UniqueLogins.Inst_InstellingIKONType = I.INST_TYPE AND 
                  UniqueLogins.Inst_InstellingIKON_REF = I.INST_REF AND UniqueLogins.Inst_Loc_REF = I.INST_LOC_REF AND 
                  UniqueLogins.Inst_Loc_Nr = I.INST_LOCNR LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  dbo.InstellingContPersDirecteurs AS CPD ON G.INST_TYPE = CPD.INST_TYPE AND 
                  G.INST_REF = CPD.INST_REF AND 
                  G.INST_LOC_REF = CPD.INST_LOC_REF
WHERE     (NOT (UniqueLogins.Inst_InstellingIKON_REF IS NULL))
```

Comment: can you explain this more? i know a fair bit of SQL but it aint clear to me how to do what you are suggesting :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use DENSE_RANK to Arbitrarily select a row. Basically create a CTE that ranks the instellinglogin and then only select the one with a Rank of 1. The tricky bit is that you have a left join to instellinglogin so you'll need to do the inner join inside the left join like so. Also I kept the Join condition as the the columns to partition. This may not be correct.

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN (dbo.instellinglogin 
                            INNER JOIN unique_login 
                              ON dbo.instellinglogin.inst_instellingikontype = 
                                      unique_login .inst_instellingikontype 
                                 AND dbo.instellinglogin.inst_instellingikon_ref = 
                                     unique_login.inst_instellingikon_ref 
                                 AND dbo.instellinglogin.inst_loc_ref = 
                                     unique_login.inst_loc_ref 
                                 AND dbo.instellinglogin.inst_loc_nr = 
                                     unique_login.inst_loc_nr 
                                 AND unique_login.therank = 1 ) 
             ON dbo.instellinglogin.inst_instellingikontype = 
                dbo.instellingen.inst_type 
                AND dbo.instellinglogin.inst_instellingikon_ref = 
                    dbo.instellingen.inst_ref 
                AND dbo.instellinglogin.inst_loc_ref = dbo.instellingen.inst_loc_ref 
                AND dbo.instellinglogin.inst_loc_nr = dbo.instellingen.inst_locnr
```

Here's the complete SQL Below

```
WITH unique_login 
     AS (SELECT instellinglogin.inst_instellingikontype, 
                instellinglogin.inst_instellingikon_ref, 
                instellinglogin.inst_loc_ref, 
                instellinglogin.inst_loc_nr, 
                Dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY 
                instellinglogin.inst_instellingikontype, 
                instellinglogin.inst_instellingikon_ref, 
                instellinglogin.inst_loc_ref, 
                instellinglogin.inst_loc_nr) AS therank) 
SELECT dbo.instellinggegevens.inst_subtype, 
       dbo.instellinggegevens.inst_bron, 
       dbo.instellinggegevens.inst_instellingsnummer, 
       dbo.instellinggegevens.inst_naam, 
       dbo.instellinggegevens.inst_kortenaam, 
       dbo.instellinggegevens.inst_vestigingsnaam, 
       dbo.instellinggegevens.inst_roepnaam, 
       dbo.instellinggegevens.inst_statuut, 
       dbo.instellinggegevens.onderwijsniveau_ref, 
       dbo.instellinggegevens.onderwijssoort_ref, 
       dbo.instellinggegevens.datum_tot, 
       dbo.instellinggegevens.datum_van, 
       dbo.instellinggegevens.verbond_ref, 
       dbo.instellinggegevens.vsko_lid, 
       dbo.instellinggegevens.net_ref, 
       dbo.instellingen.inst_id, 
       dbo.instellingen.inst_type, 
       dbo.instellingen.inst_ref, 
       dbo.instellingen.inst_loc_ref, 
       dbo.instellingen.inst_locnr, 
       dbo.instellingen.opt_kalstandaard, 
       dbo.instellingtelecom.inst_tel, 
       dbo.instellingtelecom.inst_fax, 
       dbo.instellingtelecom.inst_email, 
       dbo.instellingtelecom.inst_web, 
       dbo.instellingadressen.soort, 
       dbo.instellingadressen.straat, 
       dbo.instellingadressen.postcode, 
       dbo.instellingadressen.gemeente, 
       dbo.instellingadressen.gem_ref, 
       dbo.instellingadressen.fusiegem_ref, 
       dbo.instellingadressen.fusiegem, 
       dbo.instellingadressen.alfa_g, 
       dbo.instellingadressen.provincie, 
       dbo.instellingadressen.bisdom, 
       dbo.instellingadressen.arrondissement, 
       dbo.instellingadressen.gewest, 
       dbo.instellinglogin.inst_gebruikersnaam, 
       dbo.instellinglogin.inst_concode, 
       dbo.instellinglogin.inst_dircode, 
       dbo.instellinglogin.dossnr, 
       dbo.instellinglogin.instelling_id, 
       dbo.instellingcontpersdirecteurs.aanspreking, 
       dbo.instellingcontpersdirecteurs.contactpersoon, 
       dbo.instellingcontpersdirecteurs.functie 
FROM   dbo.instellinggegevens 
       RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.instellingen 
         ON dbo.instellinggegevens.inst_type = dbo.instellingen.inst_type 
            AND dbo.instellinggegevens.inst_ref = dbo.instellingen.inst_ref 
            AND dbo.instellinggegevens.inst_loc_ref = 
                dbo.instellingen.inst_loc_ref 
            AND dbo.instellinggegevens.inst_locnr = dbo.instellingen.inst_locnr 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.instellingtelecom 
         ON dbo.instellinggegevens.inst_type = dbo.instellingtelecom.inst_type 
            AND dbo.instellinggegevens.inst_ref = dbo.instellingtelecom.inst_ref 
            AND dbo.instellinggegevens.inst_loc_ref = 
                dbo.instellingtelecom.inst_loc_ref 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.instellingadressen 
         ON dbo.instellinggegevens.inst_type = dbo.instellingadressen.inst_type 
            AND dbo.instellinggegevens.inst_ref = 
                dbo.instellingadressen.inst_ref 
            AND dbo.instellinggegevens.inst_loc_ref = 
                dbo.instellingadressen.inst_loc_ref 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (dbo.instellinglogin 
                        INNER JOIN unique_login 
                          ON dbo.instellinglogin.inst_instellingikontype = 
                                  unique_login .inst_instellingikontype 
                             AND dbo.instellinglogin.inst_instellingikon_ref = 
                                 unique_login.inst_instellingikon_ref 
                             AND dbo.instellinglogin.inst_loc_ref = 
                                 unique_login.inst_loc_ref 
                             AND dbo.instellinglogin.inst_loc_nr = 
                                 unique_login.inst_loc_nr 
                             AND unique_login.therank = 1 ) 
         ON dbo.instellinglogin.inst_instellingikontype = 
            dbo.instellingen.inst_type 
            AND dbo.instellinglogin.inst_instellingikon_ref = 
                dbo.instellingen.inst_ref 
            AND dbo.instellinglogin.inst_loc_ref = dbo.instellingen.inst_loc_ref 
            AND dbo.instellinglogin.inst_loc_nr = dbo.instellingen.inst_locnr 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.instellingcontpersdirecteurs 
         ON dbo.instellinggegevens.inst_type = 
            dbo.instellingcontpersdirecteurs.inst_type 
            AND dbo.instellinggegevens.inst_ref = 
                dbo.instellingcontpersdirecteurs.inst_ref 
            AND dbo.instellinggegevens.inst_loc_ref = 
                dbo.instellingcontpersdirecteurs.inst_loc_ref 
WHERE  ( NOT ( dbo.instellinglogin.inst_instellingikon_ref IS NULL ) )
```

Comment: i tried this but i get the error: The multi-part identifier instellinglogin.inst_instellingikontype could not be found. this repeated 2 times for all of the 'keys'

Answer (score 1):

Or you could substitute the IntellingLogin table in the query with a derived table such as:

```
(SELECT RN = row_number() over
(partition by INST_LOC_REF,
INST_LOCNR, INST_REF, INST_TYPE order
by Datum_tot) , *  From
InstellingLogin) A
```

and add in the join condition: A.RN = 1

Comment: although the cross apply is likely to have better performance since it does an index seek on the InstellingLogin table and not an index scan as the others...

Comment: i tested it. it works as fast if not a bit faster than the cross apply.