# SQL Server view with a 'select where x is not null' takes ages to complete

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I have a complex view, which is described here: [View of multiple tables. Need to remove "doubles" defined by 1 table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5569816/view-of-multiple-tables-need-to-remove-doubles-defined-by-1-table)

I used a `Cross Apply` in it, and the code is this: (please do check the url above to understand the view)

```
    SELECT    dbo.InstellingGegevens.INST_SUBTYPE
            , dbo.InstellingGegevens.INST_BRON
            , dbo.InstellingGegevens.INST_INSTELLINGSNUMMER
            , dbo.InstellingGegevens.INST_NAAM
            , dbo.InstellingGegevens.INST_KORTENAAM
            , dbo.InstellingGegevens.INST_VESTIGINGSNAAM
            , dbo.InstellingGegevens.INST_ROEPNAAM
            , dbo.InstellingGegevens.INST_STATUUT
            , dbo.InstellingGegevens.ONDERWIJSNIVEAU_REF
            , dbo.InstellingGegevens.ONDERWIJSSOORT_REF
            , dbo.InstellingGegevens.DATUM_TOT
            , dbo.InstellingGegevens.DATUM_VAN
            , dbo.InstellingGegevens.VERBOND_REF
            , dbo.InstellingGegevens.VSKO_LID
            , dbo.InstellingGegevens.NET_REF
            , dbo.Instellingen.Inst_ID
            , dbo.Instellingen.INST_TYPE
            , dbo.Instellingen.INST_REF
            , dbo.Instellingen.INST_LOC_REF
            , dbo.Instellingen.INST_LOCNR
            , dbo.Instellingen.Opt_KalStandaard
            , dbo.InstellingTelecom.INST_TEL
            , dbo.InstellingTelecom.INST_FAX
            , dbo.InstellingTelecom.INST_EMAIL
            , dbo.InstellingTelecom.INST_WEB
            , dbo.InstellingAdressen.SOORT
            , dbo.InstellingAdressen.STRAAT
            , dbo.InstellingAdressen.POSTCODE
            , dbo.InstellingAdressen.GEMEENTE
            , dbo.InstellingAdressen.GEM_REF
            , dbo.InstellingAdressen.FUSIEGEM_REF
            , dbo.InstellingAdressen.FUSIEGEM
            , dbo.InstellingAdressen.ALFA_G
            , dbo.InstellingAdressen.PROVINCIE
            , dbo.InstellingAdressen.BISDOM
            , dbo.InstellingAdressen.ARRONDISSEMENT
            , dbo.InstellingAdressen.GEWEST
            , dbo.InstellingContPersDirecteurs.AANSPREKING
            , dbo.InstellingContPersDirecteurs.CONTACTPERSOON
            , dbo.InstellingContPersDirecteurs.FUNCTIE
            , InstellingLogin.Inst_Gebruikersnaam
            , InstellingLogin.Inst_Concode
            , InstellingLogin.Inst_DirCode
            , InstellingLogin.DOSSNR
            , InstellingLogin.Instelling_ID
FROM dbo.InstellingGegevens 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.Instellingen 
    ON dbo.InstellingGegevens.INST_TYPE = dbo.Instellingen.INST_TYPE 
    AND dbo.InstellingGegevens.INST_REF = dbo.Instellingen.INST_REF 
    AND dbo.InstellingGegevens.INST_LOC_REF = dbo.Instellingen.INST_LOC_REF
    AND dbo.InstellingGegevens.INST_LOCNR = dbo.Instellingen.INST_LOCNR 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.InstellingTelecom 
    ON dbo.InstellingGegevens.INST_TYPE = dbo.InstellingTelecom.INST_TYPE 
    AND dbo.InstellingGegevens.INST_REF = dbo.InstellingTelecom.INST_REF 
    AND dbo.InstellingGegevens.INST_LOC_REF = dbo.InstellingTelecom.INST_LOC_REF 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.InstellingAdressen 
    ON dbo.InstellingGegevens.INST_TYPE = dbo.InstellingAdressen.INST_TYPE 
    AND  dbo.InstellingGegevens.INST_REF = dbo.InstellingAdressen.INST_REF 
    AND  dbo.InstellingGegevens.INST_LOC_REF = dbo.InstellingAdressen.INST_LOC_REF 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.InstellingContPersDirecteurs 
    ON dbo.InstellingGegevens.INST_TYPE = dbo.InstellingContPersDirecteurs.INST_TYPE 
    AND dbo.InstellingGegevens.INST_REF = dbo.InstellingContPersDirecteurs.INST_REF 
    AND dbo.InstellingGegevens.INST_LOC_REF = dbo.InstellingContPersDirecteurs.INST_LOC_REF 
CROSS APPLY
      (SELECT  TOP (1) *
        FROM  InstellingLogin AS il
        WHERE Instellingen.INST_LOC_REF = il.Inst_Loc_REF 
            AND Instellingen.INST_LOCNR = il.Inst_Loc_Nr 
            AND Instellingen.INST_REF = il.Inst_InstellingIKON_REF 
            AND Instellingen.INST_TYPE = il.Inst_InstellingIKONType
        ORDER BY CASE 
                    WHEN il.datum_tot IS NULL 
                    THEN 0 ELSE 1 
                    END
                    , il.datum_tot DESC) InstellingLogin
```

This view returns me about 5.5k rows, in about 1s. This is fast!

However!

When I call this view with a where clause:

```
SELECT *
  FROM [Tink].[dbo].[InstellingAlleDetails]
  where gemeente is not null and (DATUM_TOT is null or DATUM_TOT > GETDATE())
  order by GEMEENTE, POSTCODE,STRAAT, INST_NAAM
```

it takes 1min 20s to return all rows.

When I drop the `gemeente is not null` part, it takes again 1s.

`Gemeente` is a varchar(255). I also tried it with `Inst_Naam is not null` and that also took about 1min 30s.

Why does this `is not null` take so much time? And more importantly: how do I fix this?

Comment: `Inst_Naam` doesn't appear in this view... As HLGEM says, you really need to run both queries (with/without the `is null` condition), and compare the execution plans. If you can determine the differences, add them to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why. Probably SQL Server comes up with a query plan that is not so good.

You could try to first run the query without `gemeente is not null` and put the result in a temp table and then query the temp table with `gemeente is not null`.

```
select *
into #TempTable
from YourView

select *
from #TempTable
where gemeente is not null

drop table #TempTable
```

Comment: so that'd mean to create a table, or is there an easy way to create a temp table?

Comment: @Stefanvds – Updated answer with some code that creates a temp table, use it and drops it when done.

Answer (score 1):

First check the execution plans on both the query with and without that is not null and see the differences.

BTW are any of these joins to other views? That can cause tremendous performance problems.

Comment: Yes, `InstellingContPersDirecteurs` is a view, but that's not the issue i think. without the `cross apply` it works fast (1s) i guess it has to do with the `cross apply` then

Comment: I doubt it's the `CROSS APPLY` specifically.  With a query this complicated (several views, outer joins, cross apply, they all add up), you may simply have reached a point where the optimiser's attempts to gain benefit from the "IS NOT NULL" predicate is leading to faulty conclusions.  Inserting results in to an intermediate table, then processing that intermediate table, is the only way I personally have found of preventing this.