# situations requiring temporary tables in stored procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Can anyone explain the situations in which we need to make use of temporary tables in stored procedures?

Comment: Sometimes in might be good for performance to break down a complicated query into smaller parts. That was the solution in this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5581965/sql-server-view-with-a-select-where-x-is-not-null-takes-ages-to-complete/5582058#5582058

Comment: Could you please explain me giving Example.

Comment: There is an example in the question I linked against.

Comment: @Mikael Eriksson: Thankq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many cases where a complex join can really trip up the optimizer and make it do very expensive things. Sometimes the easiest way to cool the optimizer down is to break the complex query into smaller parts. You'll find a lot of misinformation out there about using a @table variable instead of a #temp table because @table variables always live in memory - this is a myth and don't believe it.

You may also find this worthwhile if you have an outlier query that would really benefit from a different index that is not on the base table, and you are not permitted (or it may be detrimental) to add that index to the base table (it may be an alternate clustered index, for example). A way to get around that would be to put the data in a #temp table (it may be a limited subset of the base table, acting like a filtered index), create the alternate index on the #temp table, and run the join against the #temp table. This is especially true if the data filtered into the #temp table is going to be used multiple times.

There are also times when you need to make many updates against some data, but you don't want to update the base table multiple times. You may have multiple things you need to do against a variety of other data that can't be done in one query. It can be more efficient to put the affected data into a #temp table, perform your series of calculations / modifications, then update back to the base table once instead of n times. If you use a transaction here against the base tables you could be locking them from your users for an extended period of time.

Another example is if you are using linked servers and the join across servers turns out to be very expensive. Instead you can stuff the remote data into a local #temp table first, create indexes on it locally, and run the query locally.